# Should a non-blocking code push CPU to 100%

Tags: cpu-usage

I've been thinking today about NodeJS and it attitude towards blocking, it got me thinking, if a block of code is purely non-blocking, say calculating some real long alogirthm and variables are all present in the stack etc.. should this push a single core non hyperthreaded to CPU as Windows Task Manager defines it to 100% as it aims to complete this task as quickly as possible? Say  that this is generally calculation that can take minutes.

Comment: Encouraging answers, the next time a sys admin tells me my non-blocking app is using 100% CPU I'll take it as a complement...

Comment: THE busy loops killer line in windows
::MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(0, NULL, FALSE, 1, NULL);

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it should. The algorithm should run as fast as it can. It's the operating system's job to schedule time to other processes if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If your non-blocking computation intensive code doesn't use 100% of the CPU then you are wasting cycles in the idle task. It always irritates me to see the idle task using 99% of the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the CPU is "given" to other processes when there are some that need it to do their calculations, I suppose it's OK : why not use the CPU if it's available and there is some work to do ?

Answer (score 0):

As RAM can be paged out to disk, all applications are potentially blocking. This would happen if the algorithm uses more RAM than available on the system. As a result, it won't hit 100%.